# event.target.value is showing undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I want to get the value of that particurlar label but in the console i'm only getting the `event.target.id` but not the `event.target.value` is showing undefined

[image]

```
 async function initiateChat(event) {
  console.log(event.target.id)
  console.log(event.target.value)
 }

<div><label value={customer} id="customer" onClick={initiateChat}>{customer}</label>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Having an issue with e.target.value returning Undefined in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40439316/having-an-issue-with-e-target-value-returning-undefined-in-react)

Answer (score 2):

If you really need a click handler on a `label` and you need the text content of that label, you can use `e.target.textCotent`.

```js
const label = document.querySelector("#my-label")
label.addEventListener("click", e => {
  console.log(e.target.textContent);
})
```

```html
<label id="my-label">Hello</label>
```

That being said, it's not typical or expected for labels to have click handlers, and this won't be accessible. I might recommend changing this to a `button` if you intend to have some action taken when it's clicked.

Answer (score 1):

`<label>`'s can't have values, either use a `<button>` instead

```
<div><button value={customer} id="customer" onClick={initiateChat}>{customer}</button>
```

---

or use a custom attribute.

```
<div><label data-value={customer} id="customer" onClick={initiateChat}>{customer}</label>
```

with the JS:

```
 async function initiateChat(event) {
  console.log(event.target.id)
  console.log(event.target.getAttribute('data-value'))
 }
```

I would recommend using a button though.